# RegEx for redirecting URLs with specific word

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting, regex-group, regex-greedy

I have this rule to redirect everything except URLs containing /amp/:

**REGEX**:

```
big-brother(?s)((?!\/amp\/).)*$
```

How would be the rule to redirect **only if it contains /amp/ in the URL**?

Comment: Regex matching at least `/amp/` would be simply `^.*/amp/.*$` And if your regex delimiters are `/` then you need to escape `/` in regex and write `^.*\/amp\/.*$`

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to redirect from URLs similar to:

```
http://some_domain/some_url/big-brother/amp/others
https://some_domain/some_url/big-brother/amp/others
http://www.some_domain/some_url/big-brothers/amp/others
https://www.some_domain/some_url/big-brothers/amp/others
```

to:

```
http://some_domain/some_url/big-brother/others
https://some_domain/some_url/big-brother/others
http://www.some_domain/some_url/big-brothers/others
https://www.some_domain/some_url/big-brothers/others
```

this might work:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)\/amp(.*) [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*)(big-brothers?)(\/amp\/)(.*) $1$2/$4 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

### [image]

#### RegEx

If not, you can design/modify/change your expressions in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/Q31hh4/1/).

#### RewriteRule Test

You can test/modify your RewriteRules in [htaccess.madewithlove.be](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/).